# Can't load Video file in the Listview Android

Tags: android, listview, picasso, android-glide, android-videoview

I want to load mp4 file in the listview

I am doing like this

```
Picasso.with(this.mContext).load(offer.vFeaturedImage).into(holder.ivOffer, new Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                holder.imgProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                holder.imgProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

I am getting the value of **offer.vFeaturedImage** as

> http://www.travellerinternational.com/images/bannerdeal/ebd0362736716841222a59b0846d61bf.mp4

but unfortunately i can't load it. Can anybody help me.

Comment: Create thumbnail from video

Answer (score 0):

Create thumbnail from url.
Like that:

```
    Bitmap bmThumbnail;
     bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFileList[position], Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

Example:
[Display Video thumbnail in ListView](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/05/display-video-thumbnail-in-listview.html)

Comment: is it possible to play the MP4 video in the listview?